# ionic - how to get safe-area in javascript

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In Ionic I can use `env(safe-area-inset-top)` fine for CSS files.

So now I need to get this variable value in javascript files. Is it possible?

Something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let safeAreaInsetTop = ?????
}
```